# VB.NET treating True/False as Integer

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, boolean

How come both [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) and the compiler accepts `If 3 = True Then ...` in VB.NET? Even with [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on.

Does it in actuality treat Booleans as Integers, or what's the deal?

Comment: Please note that “accept” is a little misleading in the context of compilation and a conditional statement. Use “compiles” or “evaluates to `True`” to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN, [Boolean Data Type (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3.aspx):

> When Visual Basic converts numeric data type values to Boolean, 0 becomes False and all other values become True.

So, any number that is converted to boolean evaluates to `True`, apart from 0.

Comment: I see. I don't really understand the great benefit of this implementation - I'm generally a "explicit rather than implicit"-kind of guy, but that's a different matter all together. ;) Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Marcus L - at a guess, this is probably because VB6/VBA behave this way, and keeps developers used to those languages in their happy zone.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-zero integer value = Boolean True.

Comparisons of integer values can be used in boolean expressions.

Comment: Almost right. True is any non-zero value. So negative values also equate to true.

Answer (score 1):

True is equated as any non-zero value. You should receive the same response with

```
If -3 = True Then
```

Comment: This is plain wrong. Your answer suggests that `-3` is converted to `Boolean`, but it's the other way around: The `Boolean` is converted to `Integer`. The comparison is an `Integer` comparison, and `True` is treated as `-1` and `False` as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

> @Oded "L - at a guess, this is probably because VB6/VBA behave this way, and keeps developers used to those languages in their happy zone. – Oded 2 days ago "

Actually, my understanding of the situation is that Visual Basic 6.0 and VBA were at odds with the rest of the programming community in their treatment of booleans, in that for those two languages, `true` is represented by `-1` instead of `+1`. The move to "any value other than 0 = true" was for backward compatibility.

I believe that for most of the world, the important property is the `0` equals `False`. Any value other than `0` is considered to be `True`.

While in many cases, I am betting that the standards are that `0` represents “false” and `1` represents “true”, when Microsoft was developing VB.NET, they needed to retain backward compatibility for the `-1` equals `true` holdover from Visual Basic 6.0/VBA. Therefore, they went with the `True <> 0`. In this way, either `1` or `-1` would resolve to `True`. This seems cleaner to implement than a more complex conditional statement which covers both cases of either `1` or `-1`. What they landed with is essentially a straight evaluation checking for any value other than `0`.

If you think about it, this seems consistent with basic binary concepts as well. The switch is on (some value other than `0`) or off (value is `0`).

Answer (score 0):

The condition `If 3 = True Then` compiles because `Boolean` values can be implicitly converted to `Integer`. So when it sees you comparing an `Integer` and a `Boolean` it will implicitly convert `True` to the `Integer` of `-1` (and would convert `False` to `0`) and then do the comparison `-1 = 3`. It will not, as I feel other answers suggest, convert `3` implicitly to a `Boolean` value and then do a `Boolean` comparison.
In Visual Basic, `If <Integer> Then` is different from `If <Integer> = True Then`. You can do a conversion to `Boolean` explicitly using `CBool` on the `Integer` value. If you do that, `If CBool(3) = True Then` is a `Boolean` comparison.

Answer (score -1):

It is worse than that.  In VBA 10 * TRUE = -10 and 10 * FALSE = 0.  Try error trapping a boolean variable that does not belong in the slot for an integer function argument.
I tried multiple ways and failed.  Check out the Excel MATCH function and put a boolean in the argument for match condition which is supposed to be either -1,0 or 1.  It accepts the boolean and runs with it.  A serious VBA bug IMO.

I did find a work around.  Declare the function argument that is supposed to be an integer as variant. Then convert the passed argument to a string and do a conditional string comparison to "True" and "False". If you get a match then you have flushed out the boolean and can raise an error.